# Why is the estimated coefficients different by fitlm and regress commands

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, matlab

I am working on a regression problem. There are two commands in Matlab for doing multiple linear regression. They are 'regress' and 'fitlm'. Why is both the function giving different outputs.

Here is the code

```
% X = input data
% Y = outcome    

% Using the fitlm command to estimate the multiple linear regression model
lin_mdl = fitlm(X,Y);
b1 = lin_mdl.Coefficients.Estimate;

% Using the regress command to estimate the multiple linear regression model
b = regress(Y,X)
b2 = [mean(Y) - b'*mean(X)'; b] % to estimate the intercept term

% Comparing the coefficients
[b1 b2]
```

The output is

```
ans =

17.1356     0.0000
1.1637      1.1637
0.2319      0.2319
14.1594     14.1594
0.3783      0.3783
0.1204      0.1204
1.1688      1.1688
0.2103      0.2103
0.1817      0.1817
0.7232      0.7232
0.1832      0.1832
0.0504      0.0504
0           17.1356
135.8924    153.0281
39.8538     39.8538
9.4579      9.4579
0.0452      0.0452
0.6175      0.6175
0.2658      0.2658
0.2980      0.2980
0.3391      0.3391
0.3060      0.3060
0.3109      0.3109
0.0031      0.0031
18.0225     18.0225
19.0582     19.0582
19.5642     19.5642
10.1484     10.1484
12.0962     12.0962
15.1616     15.1616
25.3793     25.3793
23.5957     23.5957
25.5307     25.5307
28.9162     28.9162
32.5474     32.5474
12.9198     12.9198
6.3773      6.3773
2.7314      2.7314
2.5699      2.5699
8.3264      8.3264
13.9870     13.9870
11.0497     11.0497
20.8487     20.8487
12.7635     12.7635
13.2119     13.2119
17.0616     17.0616
18.2134     18.2134
11.9230     11.9230
26.3549     26.3549
```

The intercept term and the 13th and 14th rows are different. Why is that happening?

Comment: You probably need to read the documentation for this.

Comment: The difference between the two has a statistical aspect (whether intercept is included or not) so, at a push, might be considered on-topic here. But I wonder if it would be better to be migrated to Stack Overflow.

Comment: A note for the OP: with questions like this, please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
for people to work with. If you'd tried a minimal example you might have found that this was an issue with the software rather than your dataset specifically. You could have found a much simpler example (with fewer coefficients) that might have made the problem easier to understand. It would also allow other people to experiment with your example. Nobody else has `% X = input data` or `% Y = outcome`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the vector of ones in the design matrix of `regress` manually. The function `fitlm` does it by default.

For instance, this will do, and the coefficients will have the intercept

```
X1 = [ones(size(X,1),1) X];
regress(Y,X1)
```

Read the help for the functions if you have doubts.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. I have one more query regarding the function. I am getting different regression coefficients by fitlm function and by using the mathematical equation as explained here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197949/why-is-the-linear-regression-coefficients-estimated-by-fitlm-function-or-regres