# Why is the linear regression coefficients estimated by fitlm function (or regress) in Matlab and mathematical equation different?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, matlab

I am trying to estimate the linear regression coefficients from mathematical equations. But I get different results using standard function and the mathematical equation which is $\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$. But I get different results. Why does that happen?

Here is the code:

```
% X = input data
% Y = outcome    

% Using the fitlm command to estiamte the multiple liner regression model
lin_mdl = fitlm(X,Y);
b1 = lin_mdl.Coefficients.Estimate;

% Using the regress command to estiamte the multiple liner regression model
X1= [ones(size(X,1),1) X];
b2 = regress(Y,X1)

% Using mathematical equation
b3 = inv(X1'*X1)*X1'*Y;

% Comparing the coefficients
[b1 b2 b3]
```

And the output is:

```
ans =

1.0e+05 *

 0.0002     0.0002    -5.6828
-0.0000    -0.0000    -0.0758
 0.0000     0.0000    -0.0092
-0.0001    -0.0001    -0.1538
-0.0000    -0.0000    -0.0023
-0.0000    -0.0000    -0.2201
 0.0000     0.0000     0.4286
 0.0000     0.0000    -0.0009
 0.0000     0.0000     0.1575
-0.0000    -0.0000    -0.3488
 0.0000     0.0000     0.0040
-0.0000    -0.0000    -0.0057
 0          0         -7.1398
 0.0014     0.0014    -0.5267
 0.0004     0.0004     0.0004
-0.0001    -0.0001    -0.0001
 0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
 0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
 0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
 0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
 0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
-0.0000    -0.0000    -0.0000
-0.0000    -0.0000    -0.0000
 0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
-0.0002    -0.0002    -0.0002
-0.0002    -0.0002    -0.0002
-0.0002    -0.0002    -0.0002
-0.0001    -0.0001    -0.0001
-0.0001    -0.0001    -0.0001
-0.0002    -0.0002    -0.0002
-0.0003    -0.0003    -0.0003
-0.0002    -0.0002    -0.0002
-0.0003    -0.0003    -0.0003
-0.0003    -0.0003    -0.0003
-0.0003    -0.0003    -0.0003
-0.0001    -0.0001    -0.0001
-0.0001    -0.0001    -0.0001
 0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
 0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
 0.0001     0.0001     0.0001
 0.0001     0.0001     0.0001
 0.0001     0.0001     0.0001
-0.0002    -0.0002    -0.0002
-0.0001    -0.0001    -0.0001
-0.0001    -0.0001    -0.0001
-0.0002    -0.0002    -0.0002
-0.0002    -0.0002    -0.0002
-0.0001    -0.0001    -0.0001
-0.0003    -0.0003    -0.0003
```

Edit: The correlation matrix as obtained by command corr(X) can be visualized as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is you design matrix X well conditioned? What is its condition value?

Comment: @Aksakal The condition value of X as obtained using the Matlab command 'cond' is 3.2936e+05.

Comment: Try this `(X1'*X)\(X1'*Y)` instead of `inv(X1'*X)*X1'*Y`.

Comment: @Aksakal I am guessing that you meant $(X1'*X1)\(X1'*Y)$. I tried that as well. I get the following coefficients 4.88 -1.16 0.23 -14.16 -0.38 -0.12 1.17 0.21 0.18 -0.72 0.18 -0.05 12.25 148.14 39.85 -9.46 0.05 0.62 0.27 0.3 0.34 -0.31 -0.31 0 -18.02 -19.06 -19.56 -10.15 -12.1 -15.16 -25.38 -23.6 -25.53 -28.92 -32.55 -12.92 -6.38 2.73 2.57 8.33 13.99 11.05 -20.85 -12.76 -13.21 -17.06 -18.21 -11.92 -26.35. Which is again different. For example consider the intercept (1st term).

Comment: The condition number is quite high, you probably have very correlated variables. How does the covariance or correlation matrix of X look like?

Comment: @Aksakal I have edited the post to include an image which visualizes the correlation matrix.

Comment: I don't understand why this post has the [[generalized-linear-model](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/generalized-linear-model/info)]  tag? Are you really trying to fit a GLM?

Comment: @Silverfish ok corrected it.

Comment: I tried using smaller input matrix with X = [0.5 0.4 ; 0.8 0.6 ; 0.9 0.7 ; 1.1 1.2 ; 1.3 1.4 ; 1.4 1.7]; Y = [0.19 0.28 0.30 0.25 0.29 0.28]';  This has given same values for b1, b2 and b3.